# Including custom php page to wordpress without being 404 error

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm having trouble with adding a custom php page to have wp style (header and footer), and i succeeded but the issue is that it appears as a 404 error not a 200 success.

the header is like this:

```
<?php
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-blog-header.php";
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-content/themes/theme_name/header.php";
?>
```

and i NEED to have this page like an `is_single` or `is_page` or something to not be 404 page with that error.

i tried:

```
global $wp_query;
$wp_query->is_404 = false;
```

and:

```
global $wp_query;
$wp_query->is_page = true;
```

but both didn't work, please help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `wp-load.php`, not `wp-blog-header.php`. because the usage of wp-blog-header.php si only for wordpress files not out side files.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link:
https://gist.github.com/gyrus/3332597.
I think the key is that you have to call `status_header( '200' );` in order to get it to work.

Here's another relevant link:  http://sltaylor.co.uk/blog/intercept-wordpress-404s/

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well but the following worked well for me in Wordpress 4.7

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);

if ( !isset($wp_did_header) ) {

    $wp_did_header = true;

    require( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php' );

    wp();

    //$wp_query->is_page = true;
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->is_404 = false;
    //require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php' );
}

get_header();

?>

<?php get_footer();?>
```